# What implementation detail makes this code fail so easily?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

This question is not about the well-known and documented fact that `HashMap` is not thread-safe, but about its specific failure modes on HotSpot and JDK code. I am surprised by how readily this code fails with an NPE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>(0, 0.75f);
    IntStream.range(0, 5).parallel().peek(i -> m.put(i, i)).map(m::get).count();
}
```

There is no mystery as to where the NPE comes from: in the `.map(m::get)` step while trying to unbox a `null`. It fails in about 4 out of 5 runs.

On my machine `Runtime#availableProcessors()` reports 8, so presumably the range of length 5 is split into 5 subtasks, each with just a single member. I also assume my code runs in interpreted mode. It might be calling into JIT-compiled `HashMap` or `Stream` methods, but the top level is interpreted, therefore precluding any variations where `HashMap` state is loaded into thread-local memory (registers/stack), thus delaying the observation of updates by another thread. If some of the five `put` operations don't execute literally during the same time on different cores, I don't expect it to destroy the `HashMap`s internal structure. The timing of individual tasks must be extremely precise given the little amount of work.

Is it really the precise timing (`commonPool`'s threads must be unparked), or is there another route to cause this to fail on Oracle/OpenJDK HotSpot? My current version is

```
java version "1.8.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)
```

UPDATE: I find that even making just *two* insertions has a similarly high failure rate:

```
IntStream.range(0, 2).parallel().peek(i -> m.put(i, i)).map(m::get).count();
```

Comment: have you tried setting an exception breakpoint that suspends the whole JVM? maybe that'll allow you to inspect the state of the object graph

Comment: I know what I'll find---HashMap's internal collision chain missing a `Node` instance corresponding to the thing i just put in. The trouble is coming up with a scenario that produces this outcome on Intel CPU (whose native memory model is quite strong) without assuming concurrent multicore execution.

Comment: `value` is not final, so maybe it's a case of a unsafe publication getting reordered?

Comment: @the8472: which `value` are you talking about?

Comment: @Holger `HashMap$Node.value` for sure.

Comment: I see. However, since each thread tries to read the same entry it has written, it’s not affected by publication issues regarding the fields of the entry instance (as it has created it itself). Only the `next` field may be affected by other updates. Or when treeifying occurs, but a hash map containing `Integer` keys from `0` to `5` should not have hash collisions.

Comment: @Holger It's not easy to know when there won't be collisions on the same bucket. At the start only one or two least significant bits are used, not of the `Integer.hashCode`, but of the result of mangling it through the internal function.

Comment: The mangling has been greatly reduced in Java 8, as there is now the tree fallback within a bucket. It’s now as simple as `hashCode ^ (hashCode >>> 16)`, so for small `Integer` numbers the result is identical to the numeric value. Well, since the numbers are not added in order, there is a slight chance of having a collision while the capacity is very small, but it will never be enough for resorting to a tree.

Comment: @Holger indeed the first 16 bits are xored with last 16 bits - this is done to make distribution better for entries that have a close equality of bits in the hashcode but are different (if that makes sense). Also the number of bits that are taken into consideration when putting an entry into a bucket depends on the number of buckets. For 16 default buckets only the last 4 bits are taken, for 32 - 5 and so on.

Comment: @Holger I might change the code to insert `i << 7`. This might make it even more fun :) Indeed: `IntStream.range(0, 2).parallel().map(i -> i << 7).peek(i -> m.put(i, i)).map(m::get).count();` Fails almost always!

Comment: For the original setup (values between `0` and `5`, exclusive, and a load factor `<=1`), there can be only a collision when you add `0` and `4` while the capacity, thus also the size, is smaller than four. Just raising the range of numbers will increase the chances of collisions dramatically, while adding an int value being at least two times the final map size (like `1<<7`) guarantees a collision.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First, it’s not failing reliably. I managed to have some runs where no exception occurred. This, however doesn’t imply that the resulting map is correct. It’s also possible that each thread witnesses its own value being successfully put, while the resulting map misses several mappings.

But indeed, failing with a `NullPointerException` happens quite often. I created the following debug code to illustrate the `HashMap`’s working:

```
static <K,V> void debugPut(HashMap<K,V> m, K k, V v) {
    if(m.isEmpty()) debug(m);
    m.put(k, v);
    debug(m);
}
private static <K, V> void debug(HashMap<K, V> m) {
    for(Field f: FIELDS) try {
        System.out.println(f.getName()+": "+f.get(m));
    } catch(ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
        throw new AssertionError(ex);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
static final Field[] FIELDS;
static {
    String[] name={ "table", "size", "threshold" };
    Field[] f=new Field[name.length];
    for (int ix = 0; ix < name.length; ix++) try {
        f[ix]=HashMap.class.getDeclaredField(name[ix]);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
    AccessibleObject.setAccessible(f, true);
    FIELDS=f;
}
```

Using this with the simple sequential `for(int i=0; i<5; i++) debugPut(m, i, i);` printed:

```
table: null
size: 0
threshold: 1

table: [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;@70dea4e
size: 1
threshold: 1

table: [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;@5c647e05
size: 2
threshold: 3

table: [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;@5c647e05
size: 3
threshold: 3

table: [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;@33909752
size: 4
threshold: 6

table: [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;@33909752
size: 5
threshold: 6
```

As you can see, due to the initial capacity of `0`, there are three different backing arrays created even during the sequential operation. Each time, the capacity is increased, there is a higher chance that a racy concurrent `put` misses the array update and creates its own array.

This is especially relevant for the initial state of an empty map and several threads trying to put their first key, as all threads might encounter the initial state of a `null` table and create their own. Also, even when reading the state of a completed first `put`, there is a new array created for the second `put` as well.

But step-by-step debugging revealed even more chances of breaking:

[Inside the method `putVal`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.putVal%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cboolean%2Cboolean%29), we see *at the end*:

```
++modCount;
if (++size > threshold)
    resize();
afterNodeInsertion(evict);
return null;
```

In other words, *after* the successful insertion of a new key, the table will get resized, if the new size exceeds the `threshold`. So on the first `put`, `resize()` is called at the beginning because the table is `null` and since your specified initial capacity is `0`, i.e. too low to store one mapping, the new capacity will be `1` and the new `threshold` will be `1 * loadFactor == 1 * 0.75f == 0.75f`, rounded to `0`. So right at the end of the first `put`, the new `threshold` is exceeded and another `resize()` operation triggered. So with an intial capacity of `0`, the first `put` already creates and populates *two* arrays, which gives much higher chances to break, if multiple threads perform this action concurrently, all encountering the initial state.

And there is another point. Looking [into the `resize()` operation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.resize%28%29) we see [the lines](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#702):

```
 @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes","unchecked"})
 Node<K,V>[] newTab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[newCap];
 table = newTab;
 if (oldTab != null) {
     … (transfer old contents to new array)
```

In other words, the new array reference is stored into the heap *before* it has been populated with the old entries, so even without reordering of reads and writes, there is a chance that another thread reads that reference without seeing the old entries, including the one it has written itself previously. Actually, optimizations reducing the heap access may lower the chances of a thread not seeing its own update in an immediately following query.

Still, it must also noted that the assumption that everything runs interpreted here, is not founded. Since `HashMap` is used by the JRE internally as well, even before your application starts, there is also a chance of encountering already compiled code when using `HashMap`.

Comment: Also to prove the point highlighted in this answer: If the HashMap is warmed up, for example one inserts 7 elements to it, so adding other 5 does not cause the resize - the code stops failing. I guess there is still a chance of failure even in this case, but I was not able to reproduce even on 10M attempts.