# HashMap resize in jdk8

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8, resize

I've found the source code of function resize() of HashMap in jdk8:

```
final Node<K,V>[] resize() {
    Node<K,V>[] oldTab = table;
    int oldCap = (oldTab == null) ? 0 : oldTab.length;
    int oldThr = threshold;
    int newCap, newThr = 0;
    if (oldCap > 0) {
        if (oldCap >= MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {
            threshold = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            return oldTab;
        }
        else if ((newCap = oldCap << 1) < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY &&
                 oldCap >= DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY)
            newThr = oldThr << 1; // double threshold
    }
    else if (oldThr > 0) // initial capacity was placed in threshold
        newCap = oldThr;
    else {               // zero initial threshold signifies using defaults
        newCap = DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY;
        newThr = (int)(DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR * DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
    }
    if (newThr == 0) {
        float ft = (float)newCap * loadFactor;
        newThr = (newCap < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY && ft < (float)MAXIMUM_CAPACITY ?
                  (int)ft : Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    threshold = newThr;
    ...// others are omitted
}
```

My question is in this if statement:

```
else if ((newCap = oldCap << 1) < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY &&
                 oldCap >= DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY)
            newThr = oldThr << 1; // double threshold
```

It seems that if the oldCap is lower than 16, the map won't double its threshold. And I found that when the size is lower than 16, the threshold is doubled in this code:

```
if (newThr == 0) {
    float ft = (float)newCap * loadFactor;
    newThr = (newCap < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY && ft < (float)MAXIMUM_CAPACITY ?
                  (int)ft : Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

What's the purpose of design like this? Why not just write like this:

```
final Node<K,V>[] resize() {
    Node<K,V>[] oldTab = table;
    int oldCap = (oldTab == null) ? 0 : oldTab.length;
    int oldThr = threshold;
    int newCap, newThr = 0;
    if (oldCap > 0) {
        if (oldCap >= MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {
            threshold = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            return oldTab;
        }
        else if ((newCap = oldCap << 1) < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY )
            newThr = oldThr << 1; //just double the threshold
    }
    else if (oldThr > 0) // initial capacity was placed in threshold
        newCap = oldThr;
    else {               // zero initial threshold signifies using defaults
        newCap = DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY;
        newThr = (int)(DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR * DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
    }
    threshold = newThr;
    ...// others are omitted
}
```

Besides, this is the source code of HashMap in jdk6:

```
void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
    table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value, e);
    if (size++ >= threshold)
        resize(2 * table.length);
}
...
void resize(int newCapacity) {
    Entry[] oldTable = table;
    int oldCapacity = oldTable.length;
    if (oldCapacity == MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {
        threshold = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        return;
    }

    Entry[] newTable = new Entry[newCapacity];
    transfer(newTable);
    table = newTable;
    threshold = (int)(newCapacity * loadFactor);
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: The implementations of HashMaps tend to be full of magic numbers and micro-optimizations that only experts care about. My only guess is that somebody found that this was faster than the old code in more cases, and so they rewrote it. This question is very difficult to answer without documentation from those who made the changes.

Answer (score 6):

> It seems that if the oldCap is lower than 16, the map won't double its size.

I think that you are misreading the code:

```
else if ((newCap = oldCap << 1) < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY &&
             oldCap >= DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY)
        newThr = oldThr << 1; // double threshold
```

Notice the `(newCap = oldCap << 1)` subexpression?  That is an *unconditional* assignment ... and it is doubling the capacity.

Also you suggest this:

```
newThr = oldThr << 1; //just double the size
```

I think you are missing the distinction between the *capacity* and the *threshold*. The `newThr` value is not the "size".

- The *capacity* is the size of the hash array
- The *threshold* is the number that hash table entries allowed before a resize is triggered.  Up to a certain point, the threshold is `capacity * loadFactor`.  When the maximum capacity is reached, the threshold becomes effectively infinite (represented as `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

The HashMap class underwent a large-scale rewrite in Java 8.  One of the many things that they did was to allocate the hash array lazily ... so that an empty `HashMap` occupies less memory.  Some of the extra complexity in resize is due to that.

Finally, this code has been heavily optimized, and some of the convoluted nature of the code could be a consequence of that.

Comment: The optimization isn’t so hard to understand. The formal definition of the new threshold is `newCap * loadFactor` whereas `loadFactor` is a floating point value. But when you double the capacity, you know that the new threshold will also be the double of the old threshold, so you can do this with integer arithmetic (left shift by one), without needing a floating point multiplication nor type conversions. However, when the numbers are too small, you can’t do that, as the rounding errors would be too high. Further, you have to care when the new threshold doesn’t fit into an `int`. That’s all.

Comment: @Holger - Yea.  My "convoluted" label is relative.

Comment: @StephenC Sorry it's my fault. The "size" should be "threshold",Thank you for pointing that. I've just fixed it in my question.

Comment: @Holger - I think it's the right answer.Thank you, Holger. And thank you too,  Stephen C.

Comment: @Holger Could you please give some examples to explain what you say?I've debugged the source code, and found that whatever the capacity and loadFactory is, when the capacity doubled, the threshold also doubled too.

Comment: @weaver: well, as you can see in the cited code in this answer, the second condition is `oldCap >= DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY`, so besides the possibility of exceeding the max capacity (you surely didn’t debug until this point), the other case applies if you initialize the `HashMap` with an explicit initial capacity smaller than the default initial size. To be fair, I’m familiar with this because I analyzed  [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40927934/2711488) recently, where this is the case.