# HashMap resize() while single thread writing and multiple threads reading

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

First of all, am I correct to assume that if there's always going to be a single writer thread, then I should be safe to use `HashMap` but not `ConcurrentHashMap`?

In `HashMap#resize` (java 17), what it does is

```java
Node<K,V>[] oldTab = table; //table is the underlying storage transient Node<K,V>[] table
...
Node<K,V>[] newTab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[newCap];

table = newTab;

// copy data from oldTab to newTab
...
```

If I have another thread starts reading while `copy data from oldTab to newTab` is not finished, I'll be doomed with wrong data since `HashMap#get` retrieves value from `table`, which is now an empty array because of `table = newTab`?

What I don't understand is why not do the `copy data from oldTab to newTab` step first, before replacing `table` with `newTab` (`table = newTab`):

```java
Node<K,V>[] oldTab = table;
...
Node<K,V>[] newTab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[newCap];

// copy data from oldTab to newTab
...

table = newTab;
```

Comment: HashMap is not thread-safe. Period. End-of-discussion. It is entirely possible that the *current* implementation is safe in this case (to be clear, I haven't verified that, and I don't think it is safe at all), but there is no guarantee that this would remain so. If writing happens on another thread than reading, then you need to use a thread-safe solution like `ConcurrentHashMap` or `Collections.synchronizedMap`, etc.

Comment: To be clear, even if the copying is 'safe', there are all the other visibility problems with writing on another thread than reading that you're ignoring. In fact, the `HashMap` documentation explicitly states: _"If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally."_

Comment: The implications of this code have been discussed in [What implementation detail makes this code fail so easily?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40927934/2711488) Since the order of these statements does not really matter for concurrent access, i.e. reading it while another thread is writing to it, is broken in any case, you can see this particular order as a feature. It reduces the likelihood of broken code passing by accident, so it helps you spotting your bugs earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not thread safe. As the javadoc of [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) states:

> If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one
> of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized
> externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or
> deletes one or more mappings; merely changing the value associated
> with a key that an instance already contains is not a structural
> modification.)

The fact that one thread is changing the map while others are reading concurrently is by definition unsafe. You will need to use `ConcurrentHashMap` or `Collections.synchronizedMap` or another synchronization solution.

Comment: thanks @MarkRotteveel. I think I understand you. even if the `resize` is made safer, there will still be lots of visibility issue for reasons such as `table` is not `volatile`

Comment: @wayne Even stronger than that, a resize is a structural modification of the map, so this is explicitly declared unsafe here.

Comment: I was just about to ask this @MarkRotteveel. Does `modifies the map structurally` mean that if the thread is NOT doing structure change (e.g.simply replacing a value), then it's still safe to use `HashMap`?

Comment: @wayne No, because that would still leave you with visibility problems (other threads might not see the updated value soon if ever). Just avoid a world of hurt trying to game it, and use `ConcurrentHashMap` or another thread-safe solution.

Comment: @wayne not being structurally modified means that existing iterators (still within the same thread) do not get invalid. So you can, for example, iterate over a map and replace the existing values. In contrast, you can not add or remove entries in the middle of an iteration. This has nothing to do with multi-threading. As already said, concurrent access in the presence of modification, is broken in general.