# Why is key being deleted by IdentityHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency

I know `IdentityHashMap` is not a thread safe data structure, so the below test failing is not a total surprise. Having said that, my understanding of non-Concurrent and non-synchronized maps being not thread-safe was that there is no *happens before* relation between the put of the value in the map, and the get of the value, so a thread that receives the value from the cache, doesn’t need to see all fields if the value has publication problems.

However I am unable to understand how a Map can loose values even if it not thread safe. See the below reprex,

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.RepeatedTest;

import java.util.IdentityHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

class IdentityHashmapTest {

    static class Key {
        final String description;

        Key(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Key{" +
                    "description='" + description + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return this == o;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(description);
        }
    }

    @RepeatedTest(100)
    void testConcurrency() throws InterruptedException {
        final Map<Key, Integer> map = new IdentityHashMap<>();
        Key mainKey = new Key("main");
        map.put(mainKey, 1);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        assertNotNull(map.get(mainKey));
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            executor.submit(() -> {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
                    map.put(new Key("random"), ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt());
                }
            });
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        assertTrue(executor.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        assertNotNull(map.get(mainKey));
    }
}
```

I insert `mainKey` even before I am making concurrent updates to the `IdentityHashMap`, but after all the threads have been shutdown I can see the value has disappeared from the map in some cases. Note not all 100 invocations of the `RepeatedTest` fail, but on an average 10-20 invocations fail.

I suspect that this might be because of re-sizing, because if I initialize the IdentityHashMap with a large `expectedMaxSize` all tests pass. Also I see special handling of resize in the put of IdentityHashMap, so that adds to my suspicion.

I want to understand how exactly is the value getting *erased* from the IdentityHashMap. I already know the fix of the problem (i.e use a thread safe data structure like `ConcurrentHashMap`, I am interested to understand the *exact root cause* of this inconsistency.

Comment: It probably just gets overwritten by two theads writing to the same index within the same bucket. But as you already know, nothing is guaranteed, and the way in which it fails depends on the specific implementation you are using...

Comment: Re, "I want to understand how exactly..." Your program allows concurrent updates of the map. The behavior of IdentityHashMap is _undefined_ when you do that. Maybe you coud find out exactly what happens on _your_ computer, running some particular JVM and JRE versions on some particular OS, but that's no guarantee that the same bad thing would happen in the same way on somebody else's computer, or even, on your own computer on a different day.

Comment: P.S., What is the purpose of your `Key` class? (1) It overrides Object.equals() with a method that does exactly the same thing that Object.equals() does. (2) IdentityHashMap does not ever _call_ the equals method, so why bother? (3) Your equals method and your hashCode method test different objects. (That's normally a huge red flag, though, In this special case, it doesn't actually break the contract.) Was your intent to force all of the "random" keys to hash to the same bucket as part of a stress test for the Map?

Comment: Seems `IdentityHashMap` [works similar to `HashMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40927934/2711488) in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

You have two threads working on the same structure with no coordination. Each thread thinks that it's safe to manipulate the map however it wants and acts accordingly. When two threads are doing that, all bets are off. There is no "expected behaviour", except that you should expect it to break.

A map is not just an infinitely big bag of data you can keep stuffing more data into. It needs reorganizing as it grows. An insert is not just setting an null element in some array to have a non-null value. It may result in a complete reorganization of everything in the map.

If you have 2 threads trying to do this reorganization at the same time, it seems reasonable that even keys that weren't presently being inserted on either of those threads could go missing.

If you set an explicit default size on the map then I think you'll see fewer failures. This is **not** a solution - the solution is to use a thread-safe implementation - but this will demonstrate that a sparser Map will do fewer reorganizations, which should reduce the frequency of errors (though not eliminate them).

```java
final Map<Key, Integer> map = new IdentityHashMap<>(1_000);
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael for the answer. I was looking at the `resize` function, which copies from the oldTable to the newTable but its not clear what sequence of context switches will lead to a value getting deleted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a snippet of the code from `IdentityHashMap::resize`

```java
        Object[] oldTable = table;
        ...
        Object[] newTable = new Object[newLength];
        ...
        for (int j = 0; j < oldLength; j += 2) {
            Object key = oldTable[j];
            if (key != null) {
                Object value = oldTable[j+1];
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  oldTable[j] = null;
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  oldTable[j+1] = null;
                int i = hash(key, newLength);
                while (newTable[i] != null)
                    i = nextKeyIndex(i, newLength);
                newTable[i] = key;
                newTable[i + 1] = value;
            }
        }
        table = newTable;
```

It's setting the values in the old array to be null as it copies to the new array, then assign the new array to be the field.

And you have 5 threads doing this concurrently, so sometimes this happens:

1. Thread A and B start resizing at the same time, so they see the same reference to `oldTable`. Thread A successfully copies "main" from `oldTable` and nulls out the old value. Thread B is a bit behind therefore can't see "main" anymore since Thread A has deleted it.
2. Thread A assigns its `newTable` to the field which contains "main", then thread B assigns its own `newTable` to the field, but because of #1 it doesn't contain "main".
3. Now the map contains no "main".